# Error with alignment between substrings

Tags: python, regex, string

I intend to create a adjacency matrix based on directional alignment of substrings in set.  I am unable to obtain the desired results due to error in the overlap function.  I intend to perform only directional alignment as shown in the figure attached with following substrings.
[image]

```
import numpy
import array
a='{ATG,TGG,TGC,GTG,GGC,GCA,GCG,CGT}'
p= dict(enumerate(a[1:-1].split(",")))
print p    
n= p.keys()[-1]
n+=1
print p.keys()
def overlap(string1, string2):
    answer = ""
    len1=len(string2)
    for i in range(len1):
       match = ""
       for j in range(0,len1):
            if (i + j < len1 and string1[i+j] == string2[j]):
                match += string2[j]
            else:
                if (len(match) > len(answer)):
                    answer = match
                    match = ""
    return answer
M=numpy.zeros([n,n],int)#define a matrix nun
print M
for k in range(0,n):
    for l in range(0,n):
        if k==l: #in matrix M let diagonal elements be 0
            pass
        elif len(str(overlap(p[k],p[l])))>0:  #if there is overlap as shown in the figure,then add 1 to the matrix.
            M[k,l]+=1
        else:
            pass           
print M
```

Comment: What results are you getting?  Why aren't they what you want?

Comment: your code could do with some commenting! Hard to understand what each line is trying to achieve.

Comment: So, do you only want `l` to be `k+1` or bigger? then use `for l in range(k+1,n):`?

Comment: Some values in matrix are coming wrongly becos of some error in the overlap condition.

Comment: How should I modify the overlap function so that It follows the alignment scheme as given in the figure ?

Comment: I have added comments to the code.Is it helpful to understand ?

Comment: @SayaneShome, please define more clear your problem statement. Is your `overlap` operation conmutative, e.g. `overlap('TGC', 'GTG') => 'G'` while `overlap('GTG', 'TGC') => 'TG'` is this asymmetry expected? Are you trying to find the longest common substring? Or simply the longest overlap from the end if first string with the begging of the second one?

Comment: @SayaneShome, and please **never assume a sorting order in the keys of a dictionary**, like `n= p.keys()[-1]`,  if you want the biggest key (if all are numbers) use `max(p.key())`. But I think you actually mean `n = len(p)`.

Comment: Okk @memoselyk I will modify it.

Comment: My problem statement is I need to make a adjacency matrix M where k,l corresponds to strings in the list.And yes you are right the asymmetry is expected.GTG should align/overlap/check match from 2nd position of TGC.But,not other way around as you showed in the example.But,yes in any manner,if there is any overlap,we will add a value 1 in the corresponding position in the matrix M.Am I clear now ?

Comment: If the failing part is the `overlap` function, let's forget about the matrix. Have you already identified the failing cases for `overlap`, if so please include them in the question? For instance, what is the expected output of `overlap('ATG', 'CGT')`? And what about `overlap('GCA', 'CGT')` or  `overlap('GGC', 'CGT')`.

Comment: overlap('ATG','TGG')=TG
overlap('TGG','ATG')=null
overlap('TGG','GTG')=G
overlap('GTG','TGG')=TG
overlap('TGG','TGC')=null
overlap('TGC','GGC')=null
overlap('CGT','GTG')=GT'

Comment: The matrix should look like following :
 

 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]

Comment: @memoselyk Am I clear about the problem now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptom of you bug is that for a case like `overlap('CGT', 'ATG')`, instead of returning `''` you are getting `'T'`. You can *see it* happen [here](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20overlap%28string1%2C%20string2%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20answer%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20len1%3Dlen%28string2%29%0A%20%20%20%20for%20i%20in%20range%28len1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%280%2Clen1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28i%20%2B%20j%20%3C%20len1%20and%20string1%5Bi%2Bj%5D%20%3D%3D%20string2%5Bj%5D%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20%2B%3D%20string2%5Bj%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28len%28match%29%20%3E%20len%28answer%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20answer%20%3D%20match%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20match%20%3D%20%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20return%20answer%0A%0Aret%20%3D%20overlap%28%27CGT%27%2C%20%27ATG%27%29%0A%0A&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=25).

There is not constraint that prevents your code from generating a match in a substring that is not at the beginning of `string2` and the end of `string1`. You can fix you code by checking, before taking the current `match` as the `answer`, that the match is actually at the end of `string1` and at the begging of `string2`.

Another approach, if you problem is constrained to having only same-length strings as inputs, you could instead generate all try matching all possible substrings, like this code:

```
import itertools                                                                                   
def subs_until_end(str1):                                                                          
    "All substring by moving the slice start, longest first"                                       
    for i in range(len(str1)):                                                                  
        yield str1[i:]                                                                             

def subs_until_start(str1):                                                                        
    "All substring by moving the slice end, longest first"                                         
    for i in range(len(str1), 0, -1):                                                              
        yield str1[:i]                                                                             


def overlap(string1, string2):                                                                     
    for sub1, sub2 in itertools.izip(subs_until_end(string1),                                      
                                    subs_until_start(string2)):                                    
        # print "Trying %s vs %s" % (sub1, sub2)                                                   
        if sub1 == sub2:                                                                           
            return sub1                                                                            
    return ""
```

Just uncomment the print line, or use [this tool](http://www.pythontutor.com/) to understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much.Yes,it worked exactly and giving the results.